# Whats the correct use of const qualifier?

Tags: c, c99, c11

As I read in the c standards an adress-constant is to be qualified this way:

`int * const ptr`,

I was asking my self, would work `int const i` too, instead of `const int i`.

And it did.

After I noticed they were equal I was just trying a bit arround, to get the point of `const`'s behaving. I did stuff like

`int * const * pPtr` and `int const * ptr` in different compilers,
I notified, they all treat `const`, as if the definition would be:

> "const qualifies the type to its left, just as there is no type to its left, it shall quallifie the right part"

But I could not find anything about this in the standards.
And each example in the standard is written with `const` at beginning of the declaration or just behind the `static` part.

(What at least wouldn't  refuse my suggestion...)

So why allmost everyone uses the const at beginning of declaration, as it would be more intelligible the way I mentioned?

And how to qualifie an identifier correctly as `const`, according to the assumption compilers are supporting both ways?

Comment: Well, I think people tend to use 'const int' more quite simply because it's a bit more natural to create a constant integer than integer constant, if that makes any sence

Comment: This is opinion based. People do both. I prefer `int const i` because it has less surprises when you start throwing '*'s in. But others don't and the language allows both.

Comment: @Tom Tanner I upvoted, but The Topic it self isn't opinion based, because im askign for, what the standard says!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So why almost everyone uses the const at beginning of declaration, as it would be more intelligible the way I mentioned?

It's just a coding style, both valid syntax.

> **C11 §6.7 Declarations**
>
> Syntax
>
> declaration:
>
> declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
>
> static_assert-declaration
>
> declaration-specifiers:
>
> storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
>
> **type-specifier declaration-specifiers opt**
>
> **type-qualifier declaration-specifiers opt**
>
> function-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
>
> alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
>
> init-declarator-list:
>
> init-declarator
>
> init-declarator-list , init-declarator
>
> init-declarator:
>
> declarator
>
> declarator = initializer

Notice the lines I use **bold**, **type-specifier** are keywords like `int`, `char` or `void`, etc. **type-qualifier** are keywords like `const` `volatile` etc.

According to the standard, **declaration-specifiers** are defined recursively, that's why `const int i` and `int const i` are both valid:

```
       int            const       i;
//      |               |
//type-specifier  type-qualifier 
//      \______________/  
//             |
//     declaration-specifier

      const               int       i;
//      |                  |
//      |            type-specifier 
//      |                  |
//type-qualifier  declaration-specifier
//      \__________________/  
//                |
//        declaration-specifier
```

Comment: I don't get what "define recursively" means.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: Moving `const` over a `*` makes a difference. Otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Thats just what im saying in different words, not even a piece of an answer. + its not even that specific as my question, so down vote.

Comment: The OP post implies moving `const` on either side of `*` is a style issue.  This post correctly identifies that as more that a style issue for it is a code change.

Comment: @chux I didn't say this. I just said `const int` is eq to `int const` all others where experimental

Comment: @Zaibis With your additional info I understand more clearly your post - Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, there is a lot of 'const' going on.

---

```
int * const foo1
```

`foo1` is a "const pointer to int".  The value of `foo1` is constant.  What `foo1` points to may change.

---

```
int const foo2
const int foo3
```

`foo2` and `foo3` are the same type - both are correct - **C allows both**.  the order of `int` and `const` is a **style choice**.  In both cases, the identifier is constant.  **Having `const` first is more common** in my experience.  Thus I tend to follow prior art.  Further - I find either OK as long as it is consistent with a module.
In both cases, one would expect to find an initializer like `const int foo3 = 7;`

---

But also some unraveling of confusion is needed.
[Edited answer follows]

```
// OP's experimented with these
int * const * foo4;
int const * foo5;
```

OP surmised with "const qualifies the type to its left, just as there is no type to its left, it shall quallifie the right part".  This is explainable for these 2 and appears to apply to additional samples:

`foo4` is a "pointer to const pointer to int".
`foo5` is a "pointer to const int".

Additional samples:

```
int * const foo6;
const int* foo7;
int const * const foo8;
```

`foo6` is a "const pointer to int".
`foo7` is a "pointer to const int" - same as `foo5`.
`foo8` is a "const pointer to const int".

`foo6` is constant, the data it points to is *not* constant.
`foo7` is *not* constant, the data it points to *is* treated as constant.
`foo8` is constant.  The data it points to is treated as constant.

@ugoren *is* correct in the post about moving the `const` across a `*`.  Moving the `const` changes the *type*.  That is not a style difference, but different code.

---

Ref:

C11 6.2.5.29 "EXAMPLE 1 The type designated as ‘‘float *’’ has type ‘‘pointer to float’’. Its type category is pointer, not a floating type. The const-qualified version of this type is designated as ‘‘float * const’’ whereas the type designated as ‘‘const float *’’ is not a qualified type — its type is ‘‘pointer to const-qualified float’’ and is a pointer to a qualified type."

C11 6.7

http://cdecl.org/

Comment: I didnt say these are the same i jsut said, the first 2 are the same and the others i was just experimenting with aorund to get that behavior

Comment: @Zaibis The "just trying a bit arround" leading to "... they all treat it, as if the definition would be: const qualifies the type to its left ..." was unclear as to what variations were tried as it led to an incorrect conclusion.  It appeared to me you thought these 2 were the same.  The more important question remains: is it clear that moving `const` to the left or right of a `*` results in a different type whereas moving it before or after `int` is a style issue?

Comment: I'm not even talking about the `*` just said this to illustrate, why i started this thinking. Ofc this leads into different results, as i said "if there is nothing on its left ... if on its left an `*` its refering to it. I don't get how you can't filter this out of my question :x anyway, the first part i eddited...

Comment: @Zaibis With your additional info I see your "const qualifies the type to its left ..." is correct and have edited my post.